# whats wrong in this logic of finding longest common child of string

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

i came up with this logic to find longest common child of two strings of equal length but it runs successfuly only on simple outputs and fails others,pls guide me what i am doing wrong here.

```
        String a, b;
        int sum = 0;
        int[] ar,br;
        ar = new int[26];
        br = new int[26];
        a = Console.ReadLine();
        b = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
           ar[(a[i] - 65)]++;
            br[(b[i] - 65)]++;


        }

        for(int i =0;i<ar.Length;i++)
        {
            if (ar[i] <= br[i]) { sum += ar[i]; }
            else sum += br[i];
        }
        Console.Write(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

output:
AA
BB
0 correct.
HARRRY
SALLY
2 correct

for both above input it runs but when i submit for evaluation it fails on their test cases.i cant access their testacase on which my logic fails.i wanna know where does my logic fails.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Retrieve_the_Longest_Substring

Comment: Perhaps if you tried it with "harry" and "sally" rather than "HARRY" and "SALLY"...

Comment: @MatthewWatson ascii value of uppercase letters starts with 65.. so its correct.

Comment: @OP can you please explain what your second loop is doing..you can't possibly find common sub-string with just 3 statements and a loop

Comment: @thunderbird And how big are the `ar[]` and `br[]` arrays? ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson 26 there are 26 letters in the english alphabet.

Comment: I would think order matters. What does your code say about `ABC` and `CBA`, and what would be the expected result?

Comment: @DanielFischer the result would be 3..his second loop is all wrong.

Comment: @thunderbird And what is `'a' - 65`? It's `97-65` which is `32` which is... bigger than 26. So if the input consists of any lowercase errors it will throw an exception.

Comment: @thunderbird That was a rhetorical question.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you missed the point.he is only using uppercase letters.

Comment: @thunderbird The OP says "i cant access their testacase on which my logic fails" - I think that their testcase might have lowercase letters in it, and *that's* why it's failing. That's the point I'm making. He doesn't *know* what test case they are using.

Comment: @MatthewWatson probably i thought he was converting the strings to uppercase letters at the beginning but i guess he isn't btw his logic completely fails at finding common substrings.

Comment: @thunderbird Yes, I agree with that completely. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is all wrong. It is simply finding the count of characters that occur in both the array and the count is only updated with the the no. of the common characters contained in the string containing the least no. of these common characters.

refer this link for the correct implementation.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Retrieve_the_Longest_Substring

Also convert your input to uppercase characters using `String.ToUpper` before you use the input string.